# Jmeter Java Request

Tags: jmeter

I have a java Request in Jmeter for which I wrote the code extending AbstractJavaSamplerClient and Implemented overridden method
I am hitting and could see the response in the log of remote machine
But I cannot see the response in view Results tree and save responses to file in jmeter
Below is the runtest code snippet,please let me know on how can I capture java request response in Jmeter

```
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {

    System.out.println("run Test method actual method is called here..");
    XCardService xcardService = null;
    String urlString = context.getParameter( "rubyURL" );
    SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
    boolean success = true;
    result.sampleStart();
    //try with Junit
    String[] rubyURL = new String[1];
    rubyURL[0] = urlString;
    try {
        System.out.println("RubyUrl::"+rubyURL);
        xcardService = XCardFactory.getService(rubyURL, 165, appPassword, 5000);
    } catch (AuthenticationFailureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IncompatibleVersionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceInitFailedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XCardTimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     DiagnosticContext dc = new ServerDiagnosticContext("Junit TestCase");
    try {
        System.out.println("xcardService::"+xcardService);
        AccountInfo account  = xcardService.getAccountInfo(dc, 1089765);
        System.out.println("getAccount Info ::"+account.toString());
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientNotAuthenticatedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XCardTimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XCardException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    result.sampleEnd();
    result.setSuccessful(success);
    System.out.println("Response Message:::"+result.getResponseMessage());
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example of an implementation of AbstractJavaSamplerClient is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.SleepTest.

http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java.html

As a general rule i would put the result.sampleEnd(); in a finally block.